# Mule : Mule Studio: Accessing Java class from Mule flow

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I want to access a Java class from within a Mule flow.

```
public class MyJava{
    private Map<String, String> unamePwdMap;

    public Map <String, String> getUnamePwdFromKey (String key){
            return unamePwdMap;
    }
}
```

Is this possible for Mule flow to call a method and send an argument and access a Java Map, extract values from the Map (knowing the hard-coded key).

(code shown here is just for understanding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java component in the flow example :-

< flow name="Db1Flow1" doc:name="Db1Flow1" > 
 < http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />

< component doc:name="Java" **class="MyJava"**/ >
< /flow >

Here **class-="MyJava"** is your java file

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the specific element to call your Java class.
Something like this:

```
<custom-transformer class="<your Java class>" doc:name="<name to display>"/>
```

and include your Java class in the project.

Answer (score 0):

this can be easily done, use components: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Components